# I am getting the error 'Error: unexpected '}' in " }"'' . Where are my brackets misplaced?

Tags: r

```
N <- 10000 ; 
one_side_normal <- function(N) {
  f <- numeric(N);
  for (i in 1:N) {
    X = rexp(1,rate=1);
    uniform = runif(1);
    while (uniform>exp((-X^2)+X) {
      X = rexp(1,rate=1);
      uniform=runif(1);
    }
    f[i] <- X
  }
  return(f)
}
```

My code is above. I'm trying to generate a random sample of 10000 from a one sided normal distribution using the acceptance-rejection method. Can you please highlight where the error with my parenthesis' are?

Comment: R doesn't require semicolons, unless to separate multiple commands on the same line. Also, the quotes on your title are unmatched.

Answer (score 2):

The `while` step is missing a closing bracket

```
 ...
 while (uniform>exp((-X^2)+X) )   {
                              ^
 ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much !